# How to copy and paste columns Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm having some issues with Notepad++ at the time of copy (cut) columns into the same document.

For example I have this:

[image: Example #1]

And I need this:

[image: Example #2]

But at the moment I use Alt+Shift and arrow keys to copy the first column and paste it at the end I get this:

[image: Example #3]

So I'm not sure if there is an issue with blank spaces or something like that, This document is 14mil lines so I can't do it manually...

If there is a solution with other software rather than Notepad++ I'm willing to hear proposals.

Comment: Ultra Edit is has a function to edit columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the text replacement dialog (Ctrl+H).

Find what: `:(\d*) (.*)`
Replace with: `\2:\1`
Check: "Regular expression"
Click "Replace All".

Explanation:

- `(\d*)` : first group consists of digits
- `(.*)` : second group contains any character
- `\2:\1`  : second group, followed by colon, then by the first group

I assumed that a blank follows the first group.
If it's rather a tab character, replace the Find string with
`:(\d*)\t(.*)`.

Comment: Wow you are it worked perfectly! Thanks